# Plotting in R: Removing only the tick marks in specific places

Tags: r, plot

The code I'm using for the plot is:

```
 xx <- c(-1,1)  
yy <- c(1.8,2.5)  
leg <- c(-0.8,1.9)  
x <- c(-0.5346,0.5346)   
y1 <- c(2.2486,2.134)
y2 <- c(2.3124,2.0242)
plot(xx,yy,type='n',xaxt='n',font=2,font.lab=2,xlab='X',ylab='DV')
axis(side=1, at=c(-0.5,0,0.5), lab=c('Low X','',"High X"))
lines(x,y1,lwd=3,lty=1,col=1)
lines(x,y2,lwd=3,lty=3,col=1)
points(x,y1,col=1,pch=18, cex=1.5)
points(x,y2,col=1,pch=15, cex=1)
legend(leg[1],leg[2],legend=c('Low Mod','High Mod'),
       lwd=c(2,2),lty=c(1,3),col=c(1,1), cex=0.8, seg.len=3)
```

[image: example]

**How can I erase the tick marks above 'Low X' and 'High X' without removing the labels?****

Comment: `?par` and `?axis` there is a parameter to control the length of tick marks: `tcl`; you just need to set it to `0` in your `axis` call. You can also set `tick=FALSE` (it also avoid drawing an axis line, which is not trouble in your case as your plot is alread framed)

Answer (score 1):

add `lwd = 0`

```
axis(side=1, at=c(-0.5,0,0.5), lab=c('Low X','',"High X"), lwd= 0)
```

for more info visit
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/axis

Comment: `tcl=0` would be more appropriate as it controls the tick length. An alternative is to set `tick=FALSE`